# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string× in google bar chart when number of row =0 selected from database

Tags: json, google-visualization, google-barchart

I'm using the following code to create a JSON string from data extracted from a database:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "pie_chart.php",
        dataType:"json",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#myform').serialize(),
        async: false,
        success: function(jsonData)
        {
        console.log(jsonData);
        var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

Comment: when the rows > 0 does the data include column headings?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: my question is if rows = 0 then i got the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string× . otherwise graph is working. how can i remove the error if i will not get any row from database...??

Comment: yes if row>0 then graph is created. if row = 0 then i got the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×.